# Python: Using a method to compare two instances of the same dataclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

Good day. Just a quick question:
In the course of my lecture, I recently was given this task:

> A name consists of a last name (`surname`) and a first name (`prename`). Names are usually sorted primarily by surname, and only if the surnames are the same, by first name.
> Define a corresponding data class `Name`, which has a magic `__lt__` method that compares two `Name`s primarily by `surname`.

I am unsure how I should execute this task, as I do not know how to compare two instances of the same class - as I am not given any two objects to compare, nor was I instructed to write a function that compares two objects with the `Name` class, or a subclass. The task above is all I have to work off of - I wasnt even told if the method should somehow order them.

In turn, I wasn't sure how I should define the method. Do you have any idea what I am supposed to do here?

Comment: Relevant docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__

Comment: If you don't understand something your lecturer said you should ask your lecturer. Don't try to guess what they said and post your guess online then invite others to make third-party guesses. Ask your lecturer, that is their job.

Comment: Define a dataclass `Name`, which has a method `__lt__` for comparing two such class instances.

Comment: @Corvus I tried asking them, but didn't get a response. It's been a few hours, and I wanted to get it done.

Comment: Note that `datclass` takes [parametrer `order`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass)

Comment: If you're going to implement \_\_lt__ you probably ought to implement \_\_eq__ and \_\_gt__ too or, as @buran correctly points out, specific *order=True* in the dataclass decorator then you don't need to implement \_\_lt__ In fact you won't be able to as that will lead to TypeError